# Can we ditch the Linux initial ramdisk if we don't use loadable modules?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I'd like to boot an embedded machine without using a ramdisk image. I understand one of the reasons for the ramdisk is so it can load the filesystem module needed for accessing the root partition (to continue loading the remaining modules from the root partition). However, what if we just compile everything into the kernel image? Do we even need the ramdisk anymore? I'm talking about a very barebones embedded system, so I don't need a lot of functionality. Is this possible?

Comment: You seem to be referring to an initrd, which is deprecated and replaced by initramfs. Populating the initramfs is optional when all the necessary drivers are already built into the kernel image to access the root filesystem.  See  https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt. Note that for a "*very barebones embedded system*", the root filesystem can be the initramfs (assuming sufficient RAM capacity); that's how the typical LiveCD from Linux distros work.

Comment: Thanks. Using the initramfs image as the root filesystem seems like a better approach for speed and flash wear. However, I would like to be able to copy files to the USB disk that can then be accessible by the system. I guess I could partition the USB stick in such a way that the boot EFI partition contains the initramfs (root partition), and the second partition is mounted automatically to gain access to any files I or another user copies to the USB disk. So if they pull the USB stick out of the machine, it continues to run but you lose access to the "user files," if that makes sense.

Comment: Do not conflate ramdisk with ramfs, and partition with filesystem! They have similar uses, but different implementation and purposes. A "*USB stick*" is not a "*disk*". A hybrid filesystem consisting of a rootfs using ramfs, and other mounted filesystems on nonvolatile storage is certainly possible, and more common than you probably realize. "*I guess I could partition the USB stick in such a way that the boot EFI partition contains the initramfs*" -- That doesn't make sense.  The **cpio** archive for the initramfs has to be fetched/loaded with the kernel image. So where's the kernel image?

Comment: I should have been more clear, what I meant was the image file containing the initramfs. The idea would be to partition a USB stick to have two partitions, one EFI boot partition containing the kernel image and image file (named "initrd-xxx"), then a separate partition for user data. Bootloader points to the kernel image, which loads the initramfs (from the image file on the EFI partition) would then contain the fstab needed to mount the second user partition. Please let me know if I am getting the terminology correct here. I appreciate it.

Comment: "*what I meant was the image file containing the initramfs*"-- You didn't read the linked kernel doc or my comment very well. An initramfs does not use an "*image file*" because that implies a physical medium. An initramfs can only be populated from a **cpio** archive file.

Comment: I appreciate the corrections, thank you. Aside from my using the wrong terms for these things (e.g. calling a cpio archive an image file), does the rest of the steps I mention seem sound? Are there any steps I'm missing?

Comment: You neglect to mention the arch and "*bootloader*", and I'm not familiar with EFI boot requirements, but otherwise it seems reasonable. Note that you are describing booting the kernel with an *external* cpio archive. Alternatively the Linux kernel image can be linked with the cpio archive to form a single file to simplify booting.

Comment: I often use systemd-boot with EFI machines. It just requires a GPT-partitoned device with an msdos (FAT32) partition. I haven't tested this with a USB thumb drive yet, but there are EFI-bootable USB distros, so it should work. Thanks for the tip about linking with the archive. I'll give it a try and see how it all works. I really appreciate your help!